# Webpack,typescript and import resolve

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, ts-loader

I have a little problem with typescript import statement and webpack support.
e.g. if I have module A which has only import statment inside and module B which import module A.After run webpack watch, my bundle.js output file is empty in the section where javaScript code is generate.
It's suggests that webpack does not resolve import.
Here is the example:

```
         /*controllerA*/
          export class ControllerA{
            constructor(){}  
          }

         /*a.ts*/
        import {controllerA} from './controllerA'   

        /*b.ts*/
        import * as moduleA from './a'
```

And here is my webpack configuration

```
   module.exports = {

   entry: ['./b.ts'],
    output: {
     filename: 'bundle.js'

   },

 resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
 },

   module: {
   loaders: [
     { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
 }
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your *a.ts* doesn't export anything. You need to re-export controllerA after importing it, or just replace the `import` keyword in *a.ts* by `export`

Comment: Thanks for sugesstion but I have tried do that in this way and the bundle file is still empty. But what is the interesting when I use export statement in a.ts as You told me and in b.ts without import, everything it's works. The conclusion is that I must to use export statment in every place